# Why does this regex not match decimal numbers?

Tags: r, regex, numbers

```
([.[:digit:]]+)
```

I am thinking this should match decimal numbers like 25.8 or 0.6 ..., but it seems to give up at the "non-digit" part of the match... so I only get 25 or 0

I have tried to escape the "." with \. and .
I am doing this in R, using gregexpr().

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
test
[1] "  UNITS\n  LAB             6690-2(LOINC) WBC # Bld Auto 10.99       "

LABregexlabname
[1] "LAB[[:print:][:blank:]]+WBC[[:print:][:blank:]]+([\\.[:digit:]]+)[:blank:]*?"

> gregexpr( LABregexlabname, test)
[[1]]
[1] 11
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 46
attr(,"index.type")
[1] "chars"
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

substring( test, 11, 11+46)
[1] "LAB             6690-2(LOINC) WBC # Bld Auto 10"
```

Comment: It should match, you don't need to escape `.` inside `[]`. Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: For me it matches. `gsub("([.[:digit:]]+)", "", "a25.8b0.6c")` returns `abc`

Answer (score 1):

Place the last `[:blank:]` inside `[]` as `[[:blank:]]` and use `perl=TRUE`.

```
test <- "  UNITS\n  LAB             6690-2(LOINC) WBC # Bld Auto 10.99       "
LABregexlabname <- "LAB[[:print:][:blank:]]+WBC[[:print:][:blank:]]+([.[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]*?"

regmatches(test, regexpr(LABregexlabname, test, perl=TRUE))
#[1] "LAB             6690-2(LOINC) WBC # Bld Auto 10.99"
```

It looks like TRE uses minimal match everywhere when using `?` at the end. In this case, when removing the `?` also TRE will give the whole number but also all spaces. So maybe leaving also `[[:blank:]]*` ?

```
LABregexlabname <- "LAB[[:print:][:blank:]]+WBC[[:print:][:blank:]]+([.[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]*"
regmatches(test, regexpr(LABregexlabname, test))
#[1] "LAB             6690-2(LOINC) WBC # Bld Auto 10.99       "

LABregexlabname <- "LAB[[:print:][:blank:]]+WBC[[:print:][:blank:]]+([.[:digit:]]+)"
regmatches(test, regexpr(LABregexlabname, test))
#[1] "LAB             6690-2(LOINC) WBC # Bld Auto 10.99"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Why does this make a difference, and am I going to trip over stuff using perl=T since I am not very experienced with regexpr?

Comment: The TRE engine sometimes behaves other than Perl, so it can help to use perl instead of TRE.